# Maximo dialog box : values won't reset on cancel / dialogcancel

Tags: dialog, maximo, cancel-button

i created a custom action in a Maximo app which opens a dialog box where the user can tick checkboxes to choose whether or not to display tabs in the app view.

If a checkbox is selected in the dialog box, the attribute's value is set to 1 and the tab is displayed. On unselect the value resets to 0 and the tab is hidden.

The cancel button triggers the "dialogcancel" mxevent in my custom dialog, but when I select a checkbox then click the cancel button, the value does not reset to 0 and the tab that should be hidden is displayed.

here's a sample of my xml :

```
<dialog datasrc="MAINRECORD" id="showrbean" label="Display tabs" savemode="ONLOADUNLOAD">
   <checkbox dataattribute="SHOWTAB_1" id="id_checkbox_SHOWTAB_1" label="Tab 1"/>
   <checkbox dataattribute="SHOWTAB_2" id="id_checkbox_SHOWTAB_2" label="Tab 2"/>
   <buttongroup id="showtabs_bookmarks_2">
      <pushbutton default="true" id="showtabs_1" label="Update" mxevent="updateTabs"/>
      <pushbutton default="true" id="showtabs_2" label="Cancel" mxevent="dialogcancel"/>
   </buttongroup>
</dialog>
```

The dialogcancel event doen't seem to be working, how can I reset my values on cancel ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Received this answer on another forum which works perfectly :

> Ah Okay, so what you've done is actually added the display attributes
>   to the same record as the app is looking at.
>
> So even though it's in a dialog you're editing the same record as you
>   have on the screen so it's like unticking a box without loading a
>   dialog and so you can come out of the record and it will ask you to
>   save changes, you could click no and it would reset.
>
> If you want to be able to have the dialog have the cancel option you
>   have two options. #1 is probably the best one.
>
> 1 - create a new object which stores appname, tabname, display, and
>   have your dialog look at that object using a relationship based on the
>   appname. if you do that then it wont save it unless you click
>   dialogok, so your changes wont persist on dialogcancel. You can also
>   then use this on lots of apps, you'd just need to add the
>   relationships and conditions on the tabs that look at the new object.
>
> 2 - instead of calling dialogcancel, call your own automation script
>   from that action, which sets the values to their previous value, you
>   can do this with inbuilt _previous suffix if you're using auto script
>   variables showtab1 = showtab1_previous or if you dont want to use the
>   variables you can get it by using the mbo.setValue("SHOWTAB_1",
>   mbo.getDatabaseValue("SHOWTAB_1")). once you've set the values you can
>   call service.closeDialog() although this does depend on your maximo
>   version, i think 7.6.0.8 and above maybe

I tried option 2 in my AppBean class :

```
public int customDialogCancel() throws RemoteException, MXException {

        MboRemote currMbo = this.getMbo();

        currMbo.setValue("SHOWTAB_1", currMbo.getDatabaseValue("SHOWTAB_1").toString());
        currMbo.setValue("SHOWTAB_2", currMbo.getDatabaseValue("SHOWTAB_2").toString());

        this.clientSession.queueEvent(new WebClientEvent("dialogclose", this.app.getCurrentPageId(), null, this.clientSession));
        return EVENT_HANDLED;
    }
```

Comment: This describes the situation well. I think there is a caveat with the related object solution, in that I think it will still save that data on that related set, unless you reset the set or use a non-persistent set (which is usually the preferred solution for this). Also, I think interacting with the UI to close the dialog via an automation script requires Maximo 7.6.*1*.x. If you are in a bean class, then that isn't a concern.